# Need to understand multiple joins correctly

Tags: sql

I was trying to join 3 tables - CurrentProducts, SalesInvoice and SalesInvoiceDetail. SalesInvoiceDetail contains FK/foreign key to the other two tables and some other columns. The first query is ok but the second is not. My question comes at the end of the code.

Right

```
select *
from CurrentProducts inner join 
(dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
 on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
)
on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID
```

Wrong

```
select *
from CurrentProducts inner join 
(select * from
dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
 on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
)
on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID
```

error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Why is the second query wrong ? Isn't it conceptually the same as the first one ? That is inside join makes a result set. We select * the result set and then join this result set to CurrentProducts ?

Comment: try add alias to subquery and use it, like this:  select *
from CurrentProducts inner join 
(select * from
dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
 on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
) sid
on sid.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is a "plain" join expressed with an older syntax. It can be rewritten as:

```
select
  *
from
  CurrentProducts
  inner join dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail
             on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID
  inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
             on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
```

The second query is a join where the second table is a subquery. When you join on a subquery, you must assign an alias to it and use that alias to refer to the columns returned by the subquery:

```
select
  *
from
  CurrentProducts
  inner join (select *
              from dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail
              inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
                         on SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
  ) as foo on foo.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID
```

Comment: please show me how to do the aliasing ? i tried the aliasing in given in another answer, but it does not work.

Comment: same error - The column 'InvoiceID' was specified multiple times for 'foo'.

Comment: @sequel.learner Don't use `select *`, explicitly list the columns you need from the subquery. It would also appear you don't need a subquery but a plain join.

Comment: Listing the columns is so painful. Wonder why sql is like this.

Comment: Selecting all the columns will sooner or later cause more pain :)

Comment: btw, I ran 1st code and got error - Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @sequel.learner Because when there are two columns with the same name, how are you going to distinguish between the two? Also, you will never see `select *` in good production code because it [causes problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/11683). Anyway, I believe you want the plain join here.

Comment: @GSerg - thanks. Btw,can you edit the code so that there is no need to scroll sideways ?

Comment: @sequel.learner Ok. I personally don't like this style though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias the inner query. Also, in the first one the parentheses are not needed.

```
select *
from CurrentProducts inner join 
(select * from
dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail inner join dbo.SalesInvoice
 on dbo.SalesInvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = dbo.SalesInvoice.InvoiceID
) A
on A.ProductID = dbo.CurrentProducts.ProductID
```

Comment: error - The column 'InvoiceID' was specified multiple times for 'A'.

Comment: Don't select all the columns, only the ones you'll actually use. You have 2 'InvoiceID' columns selected.